# String duplicates when printed to text file

Tags: c, string, struct, strcpy

I'm trying to write a sentence string to a text file, but it duplicates or something when I do so. Why is this, and how do I get it to only print once?

Program excerpt:

```
FILE *memberAdd;

typedef struct {
char id[5], name[100];
} Member;
Member reg;

strcpy(reg.id, "M0001");
printf("Name: ");
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%[^\n]", reg.name);

memberAdd = fopen("member.txt", "a");
fprintf(memberAdd, "%s %s\n", reg.id, reg.name);
fclose(memberAdd);
```

Output in text file when I run the above (`reg.name` input is `Test Name`):

> M0001Test Name Test Name

Comment: Printing `reg.id` outputs `M0001Test Name` because of buffer overflow.

Comment: 'char id[5]' WHY?  Please stop this pointless, bug-attracting, unjustifiable bean-counting unless you have a RAM-restricted embedded environment.  Put in [128] and be done with.

Comment: Valgrid might be able to show you why `strcpy(reg.id, "M0001");` doesn't play nicely with `char id[5]`; in any case, you're missing some important library headers and a `main()` function - please add them to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code

```
  strcpy(reg.id, "M0001");
```

is **[off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)**. you cannot store a *string* like `"M0001"` (5 `chars` and a null-terminator) in an array of 5 `char`s using `strcpy()`. You're accessing beyond the allocated memory, this causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.24.2.3

> The `strcpy` function copies the string pointed to by `s2` (including the terminating null
>   character) into the array pointed to by `s1`. [...]

So, it's implied, that the destination must be able to hold the source string, including the null terminator. You're running short of memory here, it's proved. :)

You need to have the memory to store the null terminator also, if you plan to use a `char` array as a *string*. In this case, you can increase the member `id` dimension to hold the terminating null, like

```
 char id[6];
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
char id[5];

strcpy(reg.id, "M0001");
```

is a buffer overflow, `strpcy()` will write the 0-termination character at the end, overflowing the `ìd` array. You're getting undefined behavior. To fix it make the ID string shorter, or increase the size of the array of course.

Answer (score 1):

Every C string needs to be terminated by some <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte (i.e. `(char)0`).

So `"M0001"` takes *six* (not 5!) bytes. And your <strike>`char id[5]`</strike> field is not wide enough. You get a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), an instance of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You should have declared

```
 char id[6];
```

at least as a field in `Member`. I actually recommend making it bigger, perhaps `char id[8];`